# git submodule not showing latest commit

Tags: github

i have some apps and all the apps is in git repo with submodule.i added those repo by this command

```
git submodule add https://github.com/rahmanshaber/about
```

i am getting some problems.

1.when i click on the submodule it shows the old commit when it added it. i want the latest commit of the submodule.

2.when i clone the supper reop(where all the apps as submodule).it only downloads the folders .then i put command to download the submodules, i got this error

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

here is the gihub [page](https://github.com/rahmanshaber/CoreApps)

Comment: A submodule does not auto-update to the latest commit by itself, you explicitly need to ask it to checkout a different commit, or pull,  or whatever that ends up on a different commit. The reason for this is that the parent git repository tracks which specific commit you got checked out.

Answer (score 0):

i found the both solution.

1. it will show the commit when it is added .i have to manually update all to latest commit by this command
   `git submodule foreach git pull origin master`

2.i am getting this error because i am not putting the command on the downloaded repo folder.i am putting command in out of it.

thanks.